# How to read bean validation from a component

Tags: jsf, bean-validation, phaselistener

I'm trying to automatically add a '*' to required fields on my JSF pages using a simple phase listener, using uiInputObject.isRequired(), but this seems to work only when the required attribute is explicitly set in the markup as such:

```
<h:inputText required="true"/>
```

Is this possible to achieve with JSF-303 bean validation? Note that this information is needed on GET, rather than POST. Example

Model class

```
@NotNull
private String myField;
```

Markup

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.myField"/> <!-- required field -->
```